# Is there a way to plot a line or arrow between subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have currently got a two subplots, one pie graph and one bar graph and I wanted to know if there is a way to add a line or arrow to signalize that the red part of the pie graph refers to the stacked bar chart.

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
opfig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (12,6), dpi=80)

percentage = operator['Percentage']
labels = operator['Operator']
explode = (0,0,0,0.1)

label = [f'{lab}, {per:0.1f}%' for lab, per in zip(labels,percentage*100)]
ax1.pie(operator['Count'], explode = explode)
ax1.legend(labels=label, title='Operator Type')

militaryPer = military['Percentage']
militaryLab = military["Military"]

bottom = 1
width = 0.2

for j, (height, label) in enumerate([*zip(militaryPer, militaryLab)]):
    bottom -= height
    bc = ax2.bar(0, height, width, bottom = bottom, color="C0", label=label, alpha=0.1+0.25*j)
    ax2.bar_label(bc, labels=[F"{height:.0%}"], label_type='center')

ax2.set_title('Military Operators')
ax2.legend(loc='lower right', prop={'size': 10}, borderpad=1, framealpha=0.9)
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_xlim(-1.5 * width, 1.5 * width)


plt.show()
```